# Why does keras model get bigger after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I notice that I create a model using `tensorflow.keras.Sequential()`, save it and the file size is around 5 MiB, but after I call `model.fit(..)`, the file size is increased to 17 MiB. I copied the model to reduce the filesize and see that the accuracy is the same.

My question is, what exactly is the content of extra 12 MiB that `fit()` produces?
How can I access such content? If I remove those extra 12 MiB, could it affect prediction accuracy or any weird side-effect?

See my experiment code here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/off99555/TensorFlowExperiments/blob/master/test-save-keras-model.ipynb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it's the size of the Adam optimizer state. When I change the optimizer to SGD (the vanilla optimizer), the size is not big anymore.
As far as I know, the Adam optimizer maintains gradients information of previous training iterations. And the gradient size can be as big as the model size. That's why it causes the file size to be so big.

With this in mind, when you save your model please make sure to set `include_optimizer=False` if you seem to use an optimizer that maintains big state similar to Adam.

Beware though, it means that you cannot load the model and continue training it again, it should only be used for inference.

Comment: "cannot load the model and continue training it again" - false; you just need to call `.compile()` again. This may wreck train performance, however, as the moments information can be important for the next fit iteration - in this case it's advisable to use warmup.

Comment: Yes. It's false. But I am fully aware that you can do compile again, which will affects training performance. That's why I don't suggest to train it again like that. If you want to continue training, it make much more sense to save with optimizer.